# Approximation of "smooth" discrete functions

Tags: approximation-theory, discrete-calculus

Assume $f : \{1,\ldots,n\} \to \mathbb{C}$ satisfies 
$
|D^\ell f(i)| \leq C
$ 
for all $i \in \{1,\ldots,n-\ell\}$ and all $\ell \in \{0, \ldots, k\}$ for some $k \in \mathbb{N}$. Here, $D$ denotes the finite difference operator
$$
Df(i) := f(i+1) - f(i)
\quad
\text{for } i = 1,\ldots,n-1.
$$

By analogy to the "continuous" approximation theory, one would expect we can approximate $f$ with much less than $n$ data. Are there any results on this topic?

---

Assume next that $f : \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{C}$ satisfies $|D^\ell f(i)| \leq C \, i^{-\ell-1}$. If $f$ was a function on $\mathbb{R}$, this property is called asymptotic smoothness and guarantees exponentially fast convergence for approximation by $hp$-finite elements. The question is again: are there any approximation results for such functions?

Comment: I'm personally not aware of such theory, it is similar to a question I asked time ago. However I'm curious if you're interested in such theory or in an actual way to do such approximation.

Comment: Eventually I want to do such approximations, but for this I first need the theory I guess.

Comment: One of the things I could think of is this result: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist%E2%80%93Shannon_sampling_theorem , you basically have a sequence of samples of a function and gives you condition to reconstruct the original function. In terms of "approximation", something like "discrete least square approximation" could probably fit your problem.